# C# Delegates in Abstract and Subclass

Tags: c#, delegates, abstract-class

I am programming a Programme for Vacations Control for Companies (only to learn, not serious). Now I have a Abstract Class called Employee. and 4 stages of Employees.

EveryOne has it own class:

- NormalWorker
- SubjectAreaLeader
- ChefHumanResourceOfficer
- CEO

The Normal Worker can ask for Vacations, the SAL can say ok or deny the Request. If he says ok it will go to the CHRO. He can veto it or pass it. The CEO is the last Instance who can veto it.

All classes inherits the Abstract Class. The Abstract Class has a delegate called

```
public delegate void applyVacations(Vacation what_vacations, bool pass_or_deny)
```

All Subclasses have a Method

```
void apply(Vacation what_vacation, bool pass_or_deny)
```

except of the NormalWorker. And the Constructors of the subclasses shall push this apply Method to the delegate.

passing the vacation request is final for all Instances.

Example:

```
namespace ex
{
    public abstract class A
    {
        public delegate void foo();
        public A()
        { }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B()
        {
            A.foo = childfoo;  // Does not work
        }
        public void childfoo()
        {/* Do something*/}
    }

}
```

Greetings

Comment: `foo = childFoo;` makes no sense - `foo` is a *type*, not a variable... you can't assign it a value. Also, please take more care when formatting code for a question - the indentation is all over the place here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo is a delegate so it's a type

in B constructor you should write

foo handler = childfoo;

then you can call handler()

```
namespace ex
{
    public abstract class A
    {
        public delegate void foo();
        public A()
        { }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        private foo handler;

        public B()
        {
            handler = childfoo;
        }

        public void callHandlerHere()
        {
            handler();
        }

        public void childfoo()
        {/* Do something*/}
    }
}
```

this is for exemple purpose of course

```
B b = new B();
b.callHandlerHere() // all object inheriting A can habe a callHandlerHere function for exemple
```

Comment: i did it this way:

abstract class A{public delegate void foo(); foo call;}

in the Constructor of B I did {base.call = childfoo;}

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a variable of type `foo` and then assign `childfoo` to it, like so:

```
    private foo _handler;
    public B()
    {
        // Assign our handler for the foo delegate.
        _handler = childfoo;

        // Now we can call it.
        _handler();
    }
```